# makefile implicit rule override error

Tags: makefile, implicit, rule

When building try.img, the following makefile works,
because it uses the implicit rule for %.o: %.c.
But if I uncomment the last 3 lines, it does not work any more. 
Any idea why?

Thank you in advance for any help you may provide.

```
try.img: try.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) $< -O binary $@

%.elf: %.o %.ld %.symbols
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -T $(@:.elf=.ld) $(@:.elf=.o) -o $@

#%.o: %.c
#   echo "abc"
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o %@
```

Comment: Because `%@` should be `$@`.

Comment: You should be more specific when stating that something `does not work`. Put the error, describe the expected behavior and blame it with the behavior you observe.